# Выполнение кода при успешной оплате Unitpay(платежная система)

Tags: php, платежи

В общем по документаций есть 3 кейса check, pay, error
В pay я написал код, который по сути должен выполниться при успешной оплате, но он не выполняется. Суть в том что обработчик нормально взаимодействует с unitpay ошибок нет. Только он не возвращается обратно на сайт т.к у меня нет success файла(у меня все выполняется в кейсе pay). Может у кого была похожая проблема? Для чего кейс pay, может я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unipay передает на указанный вами URL данные после успешной оплаты. Там собственно и используется PAY.

Вам нужно сделать отдельный файл (или функцию внутри вашего обработчика), указать её в системе и обрабатывать отдельным действием обращение от Unipay.

Вот подробнее: https://help.unitpay.ru/article/35-confirmation-payment

Т.е. логика такая:

1. В момент создания заказа вы записываете у себя в БД его ID и нужные данные.
2. После успешной оплаты на ваш скрипт приходит запрос от Unipay
3. Вы проверяете через хеш что это действительно запрос unipay
4. Проводите необходимые вам действия (пополняете баланс в личном кабинете, отправляете товар, меняете статус или что у вас там).

Запрос передается через GET. Т.Е. вы пишите примерно так:

```
if($_GET["method"] == 'pay'){ // проверяем что это уведомление об оплате
$secretKey = ""; // сюда свой секретный ключ

function getSignature($method, array $params, $secretKey) {
    ksort($params);
    unset($params['sign']);
    unset($params['signature']);
    array_push($params, $secretKey);
    array_unshift($params, $method);
    return hash('sha256', join('{up}', $params));
}

$signature = getSignature('pay', $_GET, $secretKey); // формируем подпись из данных
if ($signature == $_GET["signature"]){ // проверяем что это действительно ответ от UNIPAY
// сюда пишем свой код
} 
}
```

Пишу код с телефона, потому рекомендую его протестировать и проверить выводя всю информацию, например, в файлы.

```
$fp = fopen('vardump_GET.txt', 'w');
$output = print_r($_GET, true);  // складываем в файл vardump_GET всю информацию по $_GET присланную серером UNIPAY, аналогичным образом можно складывать любые другие переменные, ошибки и т.д. для отладки своего скрипта.
fwrite($fp, $output);
fclose($fp);
```